# Joomla 3 modifying < and > when I save articles - breaks php

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I'm running the current JCK as the default editor on Joomla 3.2 with PHPCode 2.5 and I have the JCK option to convert HTML entities turned off as well as the option to force simple '&' turned on.

In this configuration I can create and edit articles and custom HTML modules containing PHP just fine... the syntax highlighting, etc., all works as expected. I can switch back and forth between WYSIWYG editing mode and SOURCE editing mode and everything remains as I edited it.

However, whenever I save the article/module the '<' and '>' characters in the PHP code have all been converted to their corresponding '&lt;' and '&gt;' HTML entities and the PHP code won't run when loaded on the site (for the obvious reasons).

I have searched high and low and can't figure out what setting I'm missing, or what extension I need, to be able to fix this so I can execute custom PHP in my articles/modules.

I presume the same would be true of javascript since it, too, uses these symbols in the source.

Anyone?

EDIT: For the record, I was able to switch to the RokPad editor and save the PHP that way without it breaking. However, I know I should be able to do this directly inside JCK. I used to be able to do this in Joomla 1.6, I just can't seem to make it work in Joomla 3.

Comment: JCE editor is the best for that. Also, nonumbers.nl has a plugin called sourcerer which can help out too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Check this [extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) this may help or another methods you can check

[How to include html or php codes into joomla article](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-include-html-or-php-codes-into-joomla-article)

Hope its helps..